# I ignored bin directory in git and now i cant use console

Tags: symfony

I just pulled my project from git. The problem i am facing its that it has no bin directory, where the console is placed.

How do i install it?

I tried `composer require console` and `composer require symfony/console` but nothing happened, it finishes with an `php bin/console cache:clear` and it returns a KO exit because there is no console.

I also tried to copy a bin directory from other projects with the same version (3.4.8) but it breaks saying something like the kernel is not added correctly.

I appreciate all kind of help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using `composer install` such that all requirements from your `composer.json` get reinstalled?

Comment: how about using `composer fix-recipes`  ?

Comment: I did used `composer install` and it doesn't add the bin directory. And it tries to run `php bin/console cache:clear` and fails.

`composer fix-recipes` doesn't works also.

Comment: The console file will only be installed the first time you actually create your project.  The easiest thing to do is to create a new project of the same version as your old one and then copy the console file over.  You did say you already tried this but that just means your new project is not a 3.4 project or that you have other missing files.  The console code hardly every changes.  You could also look on Symfony's github site and just download the version you need.